# FBgraphapiurl values can't be able access

Tags: facebook, extjs, sencha-touch-2, fb-graph

I have used facebook login in my application, I have used FBgraphapiurl to get the details. But I can't get the `birthday, country, state, city`. Whereas the `firstname,Lastname, email` id are coming properly. Here is my code:

```
 var url5 = FBgraphapiurl+'me?fields=id,first_name,last_name,email,gender&access_token=' + fbcodessss + '&redirect_uri=http://www.fastabuy.com/index.php';
 Ext.Ajax.request({
         url: url5,
         success: function (data, status) {
         var jsondata = eval("(" + data.responseText + ")");
         var data = jsondata;
         var id = data.id;
         var email = data.email;
         var name = data.first_name;
         if (data.id != null) {
         App.gvars.BuyFBID = data.id;
         }
         if (data.first_name != null) {
         Ext.getCmp('firstname').setValue(data.first_name);
         Ext.getCmp('lastname').setValue(data.last_name);
         }
         if (data.email != null) {
         Ext.getCmp('emailId').setValue(data.email);
         Ext.getCmp('Gender').setValue(data.gender);
         }
         }
         })}});
```

When I try with the following:

```
  var url5 = FBgraphapiurl+'me?fields=id,first_name,last_name,email,gender,birthdate,country,state&access_token=' + fbcodessss + '&redirect_uri=http://www.fastabuy.com/index.php';
```

What change required to get the `country, city, state`? Whats wrong with my code?

Comment: use facebook api [link1](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/gettingstarted/) [link2](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.api/)

Comment: @Viswa pls have a look in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18824693/assigning-base-64-converted-image-from-json