# Assigning Base 64 converted image from JSON

Tags: json, extjs, sencha-touch-2, base64

Here the code which i have used to show the details from JSON , All detailsshowing properly except image.When i try to show the image its not showing in the image.

**JSON METHOD**

```
    Ext.Ajax.request({
    url:  App.gvars.apiurl + 'ShowItemsByItemID/userID='+App.gvars.userid+'/itemID='+itemID, // url : this.getUrl(),
    method: "GET",
    useDefaultXhrHeader: false,
    withCredentials: true,
    success: function (response) {
        var respObj = Ext.JSON.decode(response.responseText);
        Ext.getCmp('myitemname').setValue(respObj[0].itemName);
        Ext.getCmp('myitemdesc').setValue(respObj[0].itemDesc);
        Ext.getCmp('myitemprice').setValue(respObj[0].itemPrice);
        Ext.getCmp('myshopurl').setValue(respObj[0].itemAddress);
        Ext.getCmp('myproductpic').setValue(respObj[0].itemImage);  //Here the image getting       
    },
    failure: function (response) {
        alert(response.responseText);
    }
    });
```

**Here the Panel**

```
  {
    xtype: 'panel',
    height:'100px',
    docked: 'bottom',
    html:'<div align="center" style="padding-top:30px;"><img src="resources/img/icon1.png" id="myproductpic" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="resources/img/icon2.png" id="myimglocation" /></div>'
  }
```

How to show base64 converted image in the 'myproductpic' area.Please help me to solve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Ext.getCmp() works only for sencha touch components, here you should use 

document.getElementById()
```

Also set the type of data in source

```
document.getElementById('myproductpic').src = "data:image/jpeg;base64,"+respObj[0].itemImage;
```

Comment: @Fazil let me test. post that base64 string here

Comment: you can get string from pastebin.com/yVkn4rsf

Comment: @Fazil sorry.. i missed to see some things in your code.. see update